# Displaying bootstrap alert message box when an anchor is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have an anchor element which removes items when it is clicked. I am trying to show bootstrap danger alert message box (NOT alert window) when the anchor tag is clicked. i am trying to achieve this without wrapping the anchor in div. any help is appreciated.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.remove-item').click(function(){
    $('.alert').show()
setTimeout(function(){
    $(".remove-item").hide(); 
  }, 2000);
});
});
```

```css
.alert{
    display: none;
}
```

```html
  

 <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger  remove-item" data-dismiss="alert" data-code="<?php echo $product_code; ?>"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i></a>
```

Comment: You have an anchor A tag but you are triggering on BUTTON tag, which I don't see in your html.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a little solution you can rely on. It is in vanillia JS.

HTML

```
<button class="anchor">test 1</button>
<button class="anchor">test 2</button>
<button class="anchor">test 3</button>
<button class="anchor">test 4</button>

<div id="alert">
<strong>Are you sure?</strong>
<button id="alert-ok">ok</button>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#alert {
  display: none;
}
```

JS

```
var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName('anchor');

var alertBox = document.getElementById("alert");

var alertBoxOk = document.getElementById("alert-ok");


Array.prototype.forEach.call(buttons, function (btn) {
    btn.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
  var toRemove = event.target;
  alertBox.style.display = "block";
  console.log(toRemove);
  alertBoxOk.addEventListener("click", function() {
    toRemove.remove();
    alertBox.style.display = "none";
  });
  })
});

function deleteAnchor() {
    this.remove();
}
```

And the fiddle: [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/agorgon/muakxjd8/34/)

Comment: this example is what i want to achieve , http://jsfiddle.net/g1rnnr8r/2/ . but this one is done with button and div tags. where as mine is just an anchor tag which is used to remove items in a list. and then show that alert message when its removed . how can i adapt my example to that solution.

Comment: Please take a look at this fiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/agorgon/43g5pvk0/7/

I changed the button tags to anchor tags and add additional `event.preventDefault()` to stop anchor to change the location.

Comment: The thing is that is not bootstrap message box. as i am using bootstrap ,this example jsfiddle.net/g1rnnr8r/2  is what i want to achieve with my anchor tag  ` <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger  remove-item" data-dismiss="alert" data-code="<?php echo $product_code; ?>"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i></a>  `   is it possible to adapt my anchor tag to get that message box on click ?

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem with the classes your are using for the Bootstrap alert and no problem with the click event either, but UNEXPECTED END OF INPUT means that there is a class or a function that is not closed. In your case, you declared two functions, but only one is closed... :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.remove-item').click(function(){
  $('.alert').show()
  setTimeout(function(){
     $(".remove-item").hide(); 
  }, 2000);
});
```

Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined means that the JQuery library is not installed... Do you have the required script tag ? Something like :

```
<script
src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"
integrity="sha256-3edrmyuQ0w65f8gfBsqowzjJe2iM6n0nKciPUp8y+7E="
crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer , one function is for click , and the other is to remove the alert message box after 2 second.  not sure what to do to make it work. can you help you pls

Comment: You need to end any function with the } caracter, but you only have two of them to close document.ready and both of your inner functions...

Comment: i have added another closed bracket . which is what i missed . but your answer is exactly the same as mine , bracket is missing , i am not sure what youre trying to imply by having the same answer ?

Comment: I only change the indentation to let you focus on the missing bracket

Comment: i see , having added the final closed bracket . doesn't pop up the alert message box.    i guess that isn't the issue. not sure what else i need to add

Comment: Can you publish the whole JS, HTML and CSS files then ?

Comment: the chunks i published is to do with my question . the rest are noting to do with the with the anchor tag and its long as well.  when i click on the  anchor tag the items gets removed from the list. i just wanted to add the bootstrap alert box showing that "an item is deleted from the cart"   , something like  this  [ http://jsfiddle.net/g1rnnr8r/2/  ]  but this one is done with button and div instead.